# replace embded code with querystring value

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

My code:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash-player-embed" wmode="transparent" src="http://static.xvideos.com/swf/xv-player.swf" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" flashvars="id_video=7966" width="588" height="476">
```

I want to assign the value of query string in above code like this example:

```
 < flashvars="id_video=Request.QueryString["vid"]" >
```

I want to assign the value received from query string on place of 7966. How do I do it?

Comment: Have you tried googling it and figuring it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
flashvars='id_video=<%# (Request.QueryString["vid"] != null) ? Request.QueryString["vid"].ToString() : ""%>'
```